# Prove: For every real number $x > 5$, there exists a real number $y<0$ such that $x = \frac{(5y)}{(y+3)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

The title states what I had to proof; for every real number $x > 5$, there exists a real number $y<0$ such that $x = \frac{(5y)}{(y+3)}$.

Proof:

Let x be a real number greater than 5 and let $y = \frac{(3x)}{(5-x)}$. Then $5-x>0$ and $3x>0$, so $y<0$. Furthermore,

$\frac{(5y)}{(y+3)}=\frac{(5\frac{(3x)}{(x+3)})}{(\frac{(3x)}{(x+3)}+3)}=\frac{(15x)}{(3x+3(5-x))}=\frac{(15x)}{(15)}=x$, as required.

What I tried:

I tried using the following tautologies:

- $p\Rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow \tilde q\Rightarrow \tilde p$
- $p\Rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow [(p $ and $\tilde q)\Rightarrow c]$
- $p\Rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow [\tilde p \Rightarrow c]$

By $\tilde p$, I mean p is *not* true.

Anyway, I immediately got stuck.. I didn't know how to apply any of those tautologies, and can't find the used tautologies in the solution. Hence my question: how was I supposed to find this proof? To me it just seems like a randomly chosen y, which happens to solve the problem.

Am I supposed to actually pay attention to the possible tautologies every time I am trying to proof something? And, how am I supposed to find the correct tautology, is it just a matter of trial and error, and a lot of practice?

Comment: Is it $\;5y\;$ or $\;3y\;$ in that denominator...? Not that it matters for the general method...

Comment: It should be $y=\frac{3x} {5-x} $. Also, you don't need to use tautologies.

Comment: It is 5y, and I have edited the correct y. How could one come up with this solution? In what way could I use tautologies?